# ContinueWith and TaskCancellation - How to return default-values if task fails?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I read a few threads about TaskCancellations.. However, I cannot find a solution for a simple question: How do I get a default value when my task fails?

I cannot (!) modify the task itself and put a try catch wrapper around it. I could of course put a try-catch around await, but I would like to handle this with `ContinueWith` - if possible.

```
public Task<List<string>> LoadExample()
{
    Task<List<string>> task = LoadMyExampleTask();
    task.ContinueWith(t => default(List<string>), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    return task;
}
```

I thought this would be the correct way to deal with the problem. However, my application throws a `JsonParseException` (which is called in `LoadMyExampleTask`). I would expect to get null or (even better) an empty list.

In fact, all I want is:

```
var emptyOrFilledList = await LoadExample(); // guaranteed no exception thrown
```

Based on Luaan's great answer I wrote an extension method with a defaultValue-option:

```
public static Task<T> DefaultIfFaulted<T>(this Task<T> @this, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
   return @this.ContinueWith(t => t.IsCompleted ? t.Result : defaultValue);
}
```

Edit: `await myTask.DefaultifFaulted()` just throwed a

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.AggregateException

Are you sure that every exception is caught?

Comment: `default(List<string>)`is `null`. `default` operator isn't meant to be used when you already know that you want the default value for a reference type...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Not really. `default(List<string>)` is a *typed* null - it allows type inference to work correctly, in this case, ensuring that the task returned from `ContinueWith` is `Task<List<string>>`. Really, I rarely use the literal `null` nowadays. Of course, it's up to Frame whether he *actually* wants null or, say, `new List<string>()`.

Comment: @Luaan In my case, I use `default` just when it's actually required

Comment: `I could of course put a try-catch around await, but I would like to handle this with ContinueWith - if possible.` - Why in the world would you want to do it the hard way instead of the easy way??? This is like asking "I want to have a WebSocket server. I could of course use SignalR, but I would like to handle this with the TCP socket classes if possible."

Comment: Stephen, I want to use the "most beautiful" way to implement this and try catch seems outdated to me ;) In addition, I would like to hide the information, that it can throw an exception as people might forget to implement a try catch around await ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As promised, here are the `DefaultIfFaulted<T>` variants which are true to their name (and the title of this question). They preserve the antecedent task's behavior unless it's faulted (specifically, cancellation is propagated rather than ignored or masked by an `AggregateException`):

Old-school (.NET 4.0) way:

```
public static Task<T> DefaultIfFaulted<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    // The continuation simply returns the antecedent task unless it's faulted.
    Task<Task<T>> continuation = task.ContinueWith(
        t => (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted) ? Task.FromResult(default(T)) : t,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously
    );

    return continuation.Unwrap();
}
```

Async/await way (simple but slower):

```
public static async Task<T> DefaultIfFaulted<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    try
    {
        return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (!(ex is OperationCanceledException))
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Async/await way (perf almost identical to `Unwrap`):

```
public static async Task<T> DefaultIfFaulted<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    // Await completion regardless of resulting Status (alternatively you can use try/catch).
    await task
        .ContinueWith(_ => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return task.Status != TaskStatus.Faulted
        // This await preserves the task's behaviour
        // in all cases other than faulted.
        ? await task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)
        : default(T);
}
```

Tests (passed by all of the above):

```
using Xunit;

[Fact]
public async Task DefaultIfFaultedTest()
{
    var success = Task.Run(() => 42);
    var faulted = Task.Run(new Func<int>(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }));

    Assert.Equal(42, await success.DefaultIfFaulted());
    Assert.Equal(0, await faulted.DefaultIfFaulted());

    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<TaskCanceledException>(() =>
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

        tcs.SetCanceled();

        return tcs.Task.DefaultIfFaulted();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like your last approach. So far it works as expected :)

Answer (score 9):

If you want that, you must not return the *original* task - you need to return the continuation.

```
public Task<List<string>> LoadExample()
{
    Task<List<string>> task = LoadMyExampleTask();
    return task.ContinueWith(t => 
            t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled ? default(List<string>) : t.Result);
}
```

Your original code did allow the continuation to run when the original task faulted, but you didn't read the status of *that* task - the fact that a task has a continuation which handles errors is entirely irrelevant to what an `await` on the original task will do.

Of course, it's rather easy to make this into a generic helper method:

```
public static Task<T> DefaultIfFaulted<T>(this Task<T> @this)
{
  return @this.ContinueWith (t => t.IsCanceled || t.IsFaulted ? default(T) : t.Result);
}
```

Comment: Simply amazing. Thanks for the quick answer! - I'll mark it as soon as it is possible

Comment: The spec for `IsCompleted` reads as follows: *IsCompleted will return true when the task is in one of the three final states: RanToCompletion, Faulted, or Canceled.* See the problem here? Two out of three of these states will lead to an exception on `Result` access. Also I'd be scheduling the continuation with `TaskContinuationsOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` but that's just me.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Doh, my bad. I originally used `IsFaulted`, but I didn't want to ignore cancellations. Fixed.

Comment: @Frame91 As Kirill noted, I made an error - `IsCompleted` will return true even when the task is faulted. Try the fixed version instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little unsure as to what needs to happen in the event of a cancellation. This was never specified.  I will produce an answer which fully preserves cancellation semantics in a few minutes - if only as an academic exercise.